# Protecting some routes with auth middleware but leaving others unprotected

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a protected route group:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'member', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/')->name('member.home')->uses('MemberController@index');
    Route::get('show')->name('member.show')->uses('MemberController@show');
    // ...various additional protected member routes...
});
```

However, I have two routes that should not be protected:

```
Route::get('member/pay')->name('member.pay')->uses('MemberController@pay');
Route::get('member/confirm/{payment}')->name('member.confirm')->uses('MemberController@confirm');
```

So long as `'middleware' => 'auth'` is applied to that separate route group, ALL of the `member` prefixed routes are covered by it even if I don't place them in the group.

I've tried moving the unprotected routes above and below the protected route group but I still get `401 unauthorized` unless I remove the middleware entirely.

This isn't impacting any of my other routes...only the ones prefixed by `member`.

How can I exclude these two routes from auth?

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'member'], function () {
    Route::get('/')->name('member.home')->uses('MemberController@index')->middleware('auth');
    Route::get('show')->name('member.show')->uses('MemberController@show')->middleware('auth');
    //
    Route::get('member/pay')->name('member.pay')->uses('MemberController@pay');
    Route::get('member/confirm/{payment}')->name('member.confirm')->uses('MemberController@confirm');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to remove the middleware assignment from the Route group and instead assign the middleware in your MemberController constructor. That way you can exclude which methods should not have it applied, like so:

```
class MemberController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Instantiate a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth')->except(['pay', 'confirm']);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just checked the constructor after seeing this and noticed that the `$this->middleware('auth');` line was in the `MemberController` which explains why all the member routes were being protected. Removing it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use nested groups like this.

```
Route::group([ 'prefix' => 'member' ], function() {
    // Protected routes
    Route::group([ 'middleware' => 'auth' ], function() {
        Route::get('/', 'MemberController@index')->name('member.home');
        Route::get('show', 'MemberController@show')->name('member.show');
        // ...various additional protected member routes...
    });

    // Non protected routes
    Route::get('pay', 'MemberController@pay')->name('member.pay');
    Route::get('confirm/{payment}', 'MemberController@confirm')->name('member.confirm');
    // ...various additional non protected member routes...
});
```